# VirtualHost on MacOS Mojave with MAMP doesn't work

Tags: php, apache, mamp, virtualhost, macos-mojave

I have a project developed on `symfony 2.4` that run on correctly on my main computer using `WAMP`. 
However, I need to move it to my laptop `MacOS` `Mojave` (`v 10.14.5`). To do that I install `MAMP` and try to set the virtual host.

Here the steps I did:
1. Installed `MAMP 5.4` and set the port as default:
`Apache port : 80`
`MySQL Port: 3306`

2. Updated the `hosts` file located at `/private/etc/`by adding the following code:

```
127.0.0.1   mysite.fr
::1 mysite.fr
```

3. Updated the file `httpd.conf` located at `/MAMP/conf/apache` by removing the # before Virtual hosts line:
   `Include /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`

4.Updated the file `httpd-vhosts.conf`located at `/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/` by adding the following code:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite⁩Symfony2.4⁩/web"
    ServerName mysite.fr
</VirtualHost>
```

5. Restart MAMP
6. Open my browser and move to the url `mysite.fr`

My Virtualhost setting on my Mac and my Windows are exactly identical. However, it's works on my Windows only, here the error message I get on my Mac at `mysite.fr`

```
Not Found
The requested URL / was not found on this server.
```

Comment: did you tried `http://localhost` ? it's works?

Comment: Hi andreah, thanks for your answer. I already try http://localhost, that redirect my to the folder htdocs.

Comment: Can you double check the paths you've put he file into to ensure you haven't confused WAMP and MAMP - then also check the main httpd.conf file to check the path of where the extra conf files are being included - it may be that your VirtualHost file on Mac isn't ever included?

Comment: I tried the following url:
http://localhost/mysite.fr
localhost:80/mysite.fr
127.0.0.1:80/mysite.fr

Regarding the paths :
- I have in my host file in /private/etc : 
127.0.0.1 mysite.fr
::1 mysite.fr
- I have in my httpd-vhosts.conf:
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ...
    ServerName mysite.fr
    ...
</VirtualHost>

I didn't touched any conf file in my /private/etc folder excepted the host file

Comment: Ok - your host file appears to be fine if mysite.fr is bringing you to your local server - but your httpd/MAMP files are not doing what you think. In your post you talk about WAMP paths rather than MAMP paths (like: /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/vhosts.conf) - you can verify if your httpd-vhosts.conf file is even being used by adding "junk" to the very first line and if it fails to restart you know the file is included? If it restarts fine with this line then the file is not being included

Comment: Yeah you're right, I did a typo in my post. I corrected the original post.

Comment: I added "junk" as you mentioned in my httpd-vhosts.conf file located at /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache like that: 
<VirtualHost *:80>
   junk
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysiteSymfony2.4/web"
    ServerName mysite.fr
</VirtualHost>

The MAMP apache server fail to restart.

Comment: Great, so at least we know we're looking at the right file. Remove the word junk again. in your "web/" folder add a test.php file and put in it <?php echo "hello world"; to see if it returns anything. Also check where mysite.fr resolves to - you could do from your terminal on your mac "wget http://mysite.fr/test.php" - it will come up with the IP address that it is trying to connect to. Let me know the results.

Comment: Here what I got from wget mysite.fr/test.php : 
--2019-07-06 00:20:26--  http://mysite.fr/test.php
Resolution of mysite.fr (mysite.fr)… ::1, 127.0.0.1
Connection at mysite.fr (mysite.fr)|::1|:80… connected.
request HTTP send, waiting… 404 Not Found
2019-07-06 00:20:26 erreur 404 : Not Found.

Comment: Ok, thats going the right place too - last try, put ServerName mysite.fr as the first line under VirtualHosts before the DocumentRoot?

Comment: Same result with :
```<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mysite.fr
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysiteSymfony2.4/web/"
    <Directory "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysiteSymfony2.4/web/">
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>```
I also try to put this part above the localhost setup

Comment: Just a comment, but can't you just configure that through the MAMP control panel without having to edit the files directly ?  I have MAMP Pro 4.x, but I think the free version has many of the same features.  I have never had a problem just adding host through the "hosts" menu, sometimes giving it an alias, but that usually works and the pro version allows for the creation of self-signed SSL's as well.

Comment: The MAMP control panel don't have the feature to manage easily virtual hosts :(
However I also try with the free MAMP Pro version, I got the same issue